# DataTables how I can hide the title when print?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to hide the website `title` tag when print.

Also, I want to add some text above the table. Like: 'Debtors Report'

How I can achieve this?

I have tried below code for print the table:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#printData').DataTable({
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    messageTop: function () {
                            return 'Debtors Report';
                    },
                    messageBottom: null,
                }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: maybe use this [Remove the header and footer when printing a page](https://springmerchant.com/bigcommerce/hide-header-footer-when-printing-bigcommerce/)

Comment: Yes sure but I am not printing the whole page. I'm printing only a table. See this snapshot [http://prntscr.com/n9yw7k]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in your print button

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#printData').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [{
            extend:'print',
            title:'Debtors Report'

        }],
    } );
} );
```

if you want empty title then use this `title:''`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#printData').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [{
            extend:'print',
            title:'Debtors Report'
        
        }],
    } );
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>


<table id="printData" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

[check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/fnrtcu85/7/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! It's working now. I just want to confirm one thing can I add `html` tag in the `title` for display text in the center?

Comment: What if I want to use the `title`  attribute since I need to define the filename and not to show it in the print preview?

Comment: @RafeequeKP use this code for title `$(document).ready(function () {
   //var vTitle = $(this).attr('title');
   var vTitle = document.title;
   //console.log(vTitle);
});`